# Have an Electron App detach itself from its parent Process in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, process, electron

How do you have an Electron app detach itself from its parent process on Linux so that when it is launched from the terminal, the terminal proceeds as if the process exited (the next command can be entered etc). Launching Visual Studio Code from the terminal is one example of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own launcher, you can combine it with the CLI script from the other day.

This would make an assumption that if the IPC server is not running, then it will launch and detach your app. You will need to launch the IPC server immediately in your app and even then there will be a race condition but if you use the `requestSingleInstanceLock` you should be fine.

Here's the updated CLI script

```
#!/usr/bin/node
const net = require('net'),
  {spawn} = require('child_process'),
  APP_LOC = '/path/to/electron-app';

let args = process.argv;
args.shift(); // Drop /usr/bin/node 
args.shift(); // Drop script path

let line = args.join(' ');
net.connect('/tmp/my-app.sock',(conn)=>{
  conn.setEncoding('utf8');
  conn.on('data',(response)=>{
    console.log(response);
    process.exit(0);
  });
  conn.write(line+'\n');
}).on('error',(err)=>{
  if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
    console.log('Attempting to launch application');
    const cp = spawn(APP_LOC, {
      detached: true,
      stdio:'ignore',
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(2);
    }).on('spawn', () => {
      cp.unref();
      console.log('Application launched');
      process.exit(0);
    });
  }
  else {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your command with **nohup**. Example: `nohup ping 8.8.8.8 -c 100 </dev/null &>/dev/null &`. If you close your terminal, and check `ps aux | grep ping` from another, you'll see it's still running. Read more about `nohup`, `disown` and the ampersand (&) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)

Some clarification on the above example: `</dev/null` is used to make every read call receive an EOF (effectively your application won't be stuck waiting for input), and `&>/dev/null` redirects `stdin` and `stdout` to `/dev/null` (as your application won't be writing anywhere, once it's detached from the controlling terminal). The `&` just runs the process in the background directly.

Comment: Hi, if I understood correctly, this depends on the user using the nohup command. What I want is a way to achieve this through my app. Take my example of vs code, even if you run "code" in the terminal, the process is detached from the terminal.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - it depends on the user running the command. If you want to do this programmatically, then you have to check what functions are offered by your language/framework. Usually it might come down to a system call such as setsid(), but I'm not really familiar with this topic. You mention electron, so one thing I've found is this: https://github.com/parro-it/electron-detach which sounds like what you're describing. Not familiar with JS/Electron, so I can't exactly tell how it's done or if it's portable.

Comment: The caller of the process is the one responsible for it. If you launch it from the terminal you have to do as undying said, redirect the stdout/stderr and detach the process with `&>/dev/null &`. You don't need `nohup`, I've never heard of it before. If you launch the process from a GUI launcher (app menu, file explorer), that GUI launcher is the one responsible for it and you won't see any terminal output. Your example of running `code` is probably itself a launcher, which launches the real process, detaches it and then exits.